# Query shows the same results for the # of entries

Tags: php, repeat

I am using the code below and for each entry it is repeating the most recent entry instead of showing all entries.

Code:

```
$sql="SELECT theday.day_id, actornames.actorname, 
    theday.personwhois, actornames.whyactor,    
    theday.daydate FROM theday LEFT JOIN actornames 
    ON theday.personwhois = actornames.actor_id WHERE 
    actornames.group_id = '$gi' ORDER BY theday.id DESC";  

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
    }
    echo "";


    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($rows == 0)
   {
   print("");

    }
    elseif($rows > 0)
     {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {

 // All other fields I am using the $variable method below to show them
 $day = mysql_result($result,$i,"day_id");
```

Example:

If i have ten unique rows it repeats ten rows with the most recent entries:

```
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
 Angelina Jolie, Wanted, Original Sin, Taking lives
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please post the full `while` loop.

Comment: @Felix thats all i have.  I am using the print $variable to show all the content.

Comment: @AAA: There are at least two `}` missing... and the code you posted does not generate this output.

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting?

Comment: Are you aware that you execute that query three times?

Comment: NO, how?!! I am not sure how?!

Answer (score 1):

Are you outputing the result from the row variable?

Try cleaning up the code first, the next sample code should do the basic part of the querying.

```
$sql="SELECT theday.day_id, actornames.actorname, 
theday.personwhois, actornames.whyactor,    
theday.daydate FROM theday LEFT JOIN actornames 
ON theday.personwhois = actornames.actor_id WHERE 
actornames.group_id = '$gi' ORDER BY theday.id DESC";  

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   print_r($row);
   // additional formatting
}
```

Comment: Hi yeah i only see the latest result for all entries.

Comment: Then it's not your php code, but the query you're running I guess.

Comment: Yes, i needed to use $row['row_name'];

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

a) Don't run the query three times, and don't store two copies of the results resource (`$query` and `$results` are duplicates). This is a giant waste of resources.

b) You're looping through `$query` (in your while loop), while trying to pull data from `$result`. The internal pointer of `$result` is not being updated and so you will never advance from the first row. Again, only running the query once would solve this.

c) The 2nd argument of `mysql_result` is the numerical offset of the row. You're using `$i`, which isn't defined so its default value is 0. Changing it to `$row` didn't fix your problem because `$row` is an array. You would need to use a counter. Or, even better, since you're already fetching the array, don't use `mysql_result` period since it's inefficient and redundant.

```
$sql = ...
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $day = $row['day_id'];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use $row['row_name']; instead of what i had.

Comment: It's not nearly that simple, take a look at my answer.